# Instagram Gem, how do I handle an incorrect access token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling, instagram-api

I'm trying to determine if a response to `Instagram.client(:access_token => self.access_token)` has returned the correct object or if the authentication has failed.

I can rescue it, but I also want to take particular action if the access token is incorrect.

What's the best way to do this in rails 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the access token is no longer valid you can rescue the `Instagram::BadRequest` exception:

```
@token  = 'xXxXxX...'
@client = Instagram.client(access_token: @token)

begin
  user = @client.user
  # YOUR LOGIC HERE
rescue Instagram::BadRequest => e
  if e.message =~ /access_token provided is invalid/
    # ACCESS TOKEN IS NO LONGER VALID
    # DO SOMETHING E.G. SEND THE USER AN EMAIL
  else
    # IT RETURNED 400 FOR ANOTHER REASON
  end
end
```